# Express/Multer detects 7bit encoding of text file when it's ucs2. Are they synonyms?

Tags: node.js, encoding, multer

In a node.js application, I receive uploaded text file, with Multer middleware.  It's a valid ucs2-encoded file.  When I try to read it, I get an unreadable string with `buffer.toString()`. It does get the right output with `buffer.toString('ucs2')`.  But the encoding that Multer gives is `req.file.encoding === '7bit'`.

My question is: **can I make a direct relationship between "7bit" and "ucs2"**, so whenever I get "7bit" from Multer I can do a `buffer.toString('ucs2')`?  Or it could also mean other encodings?  In the latter case, how can I make sure to get the right content of the textfile?

here is a part of the code :

```
var getFile = function(req, res, next) {
    var encoding = req.file.encoding;
    fs.readFile(req.file.path, function (err, buffer) {
        var data = buffer.toString(encoding);
    }
}
```

That exact code won't work here because `encoding` gives "7bit", which is not understood by `toString`.

Thanks.

Comment: I have a partial answer : putting an UTF-8 file in this throughput also has Multer detect a "7bit" encoding, so that won't be of help.  How then can I detect the underlying encoding of a buffer?

Answer (score 0):

There is no "detection," the `encoding` value is merely what (if any) the client passed as the field/file's `Content-Transfer-Encoding`. For the most part, this value can be ignored as it's not really used (anymore). You should determine the content encoding based on the mime type instead.

Comment: The mimetype is set to "application-octet-stream"; which doesn't help.  I have got a partial answer through the "node-chardet" plugin.  What I still have to reconcile is the difference between the kinds of codes given by that plugin (UTF_32BE, UTF_16LE, windows_1251, etc.) and those used by Buffer type (UTF8, UCS2, Ascii) as seen here : https://millermedeiros.github.io/mdoc/examples/node_api/doc/buffers.html

Comment: For `application/octet-stream`, that would indicate 8-bit binary because it's a stream of *octets*. Whether the actual content is 8-bit binary or not is a separate issue and would require inspection of the content itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```js
file.originalname = Buffer.from(file.originalname, 'ascii').toString('utf8');
```